# Initialization of an array using rand() function

Tags: c

I want to initialize my input random array to find the fft of the size of the input array. I want that the input array should contain complex numbers(e.g a+jb) which has to be done using `rand()` in c. I am trying to do it like this:

```
sint16 min= Some value a;
sint16 max= Some value b;
sint32 array[1536];

uint16 i;
for(i=0; i<1536; i++) {
    r= rand()%(max+min+1)+min;
    array[i]=r;
}
```

but it is not producing the results I need.

Comment: Also you shouldn't use magic numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Consider how `max + min + 1` will vary when you plug in different values of `max` and `min`:

- `max = 10, min = 0` => 10 + 0 + 1 = 11
- `max = 30, min = 20` => 30 + 20 + 1 = 51

Now, the actual range is the same in those two examples, right?

So, you equation should be:

```
r = rand() % (max - min + 1);
```

Note the *subtraction*, to compute distance from `min` to `max` (assuming `max > min`).

Comment: i think this is r= rand()% (max-min+1) +min; Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I agree, and have submitted an edit accordingly - it awaits review.